# Redis with laravel 5.2 : localhost didn't send any data.(laracast tutorial)

Tags: php, redis, socket.io, laravel-5, ioredis

Error:

> localhost didn't send any data.

I am using Laravel 5.2 on win 10 and gitbash .
According to the code ,it should return 'done' ,BUT it isn't.
 My files:
 routes.php:http://laravel.io/bin/MkGM0 
 socket.js: http://laravel.io/bin/RE09K

Comment: please post your code!

Comment: @AniruddhaChakraborty routes.php:http://laravel.io/bin/MkGM0 socket.js: http://laravel.io/bin/RE09K if need any other file, just tell me. Ty